# How to test Web UI of a Web Browser control inside a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, webbrowser-control, gui-testing

We have a web application that can be tested using **[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)**, but that's not enough because the web application will be used inside a WinForms application using the [Web Browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The **WinForms** app interacts with the content of the page hosted inside the [Web Browser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and viceversa.

We have tests on other layers like services, but we need to find a way to test the WinForms UI that interact with the [Web Browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a WinForm test automation.  A friend of mine blogged about this recently; http://matthewskelton.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/test-automation-tools-for-winforms-desktop-applications/

Comment: Will any of those options help us to test the interaction with the WebBrowser control and the HTML/javascript?

Comment: They will enable you to automate operation of the WinForm app.  If you automate a user process that causes interaction with the web app via the browser control, then yes.  I am assuming you want to build an integration test?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the link which Myles kindly provided, I also blogged specifically about calling the WebBrowser control from C# WinForms applications here:

http://matthewskelton.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/calling-javascript-from-c/

Specifically, you can use `Type.InvokeMember()` to call JavaScript from C#.

In terms of *testing* this, I suppose you'd need to drop a JavaScript listener/logger into the DOM, hooking it onto a low-level event or prototype, and then log out to the JavaScript console.